# Creating excel file with java (invalid file format)

Tags: java, excel, file

I manage to create Excel 97-2003 file with Java, but when I try to open it with Windows Explorer, I get the error message file format is not valid. The filename is file.xls so it should be right? What goes wrong then?

Comment: could you put in the related code here?

Comment: are u using any library?? if not have a look at this http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html

Comment: just because the file extension is .xls does not mean the file IS .xls, or correctly written .xls. And presumably you mean opening with Excel? I'm guessing your file creation is not right.

Comment: the extension is the least of your concerns! you have to put the data in very specific form so that it is really an excel file. if you just need to put some data into excel, use a csv format!

Answer (score 1):

Question is not clear. How was you creating excel file with Java?
The problem is because tool you used for file creation created it incorrectly, in incorrect format.

Consider using Apache POI library: http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html
I was using it for a while and it works correctly. I didn't have problems with it.

Comment: public static void write () throws IOException, WriteException {
      WorkbookSettings settings = new WorkbookSettings();
        File seurantaraportti = new File(ta.xls");
        WritableWorkbook seurw = Workbook.createWorkbook(ta,settings);
        seurw.createSheet("ta", 0);
        WritableSheet ws = seurw.getSheet(0);
        addNumber(ws,0,0,100.0);
        seurw.close();
}

Comment: private static void addNumber(WritableSheet sheet, int column, int row, Double d) throws WriteException, RowsExceededException {
  Number number=new Number(column, row,d);
  sheet.addCell(number);
 }

Answer (score 0):

I'm too late for that train, but someone else might need help with it. Not sure if you are using any controller but what helped for me is to append the following to the controller that is responsible for handling the export request:

```
response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=submissions-report.xlsx");
```